# how to define many-to-many and one-to-many relations between two entities in code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, relationship, table-relationships

Im creating a web-site using entity-framework code-first where a:
user can sell many products: one-to-many. 
user can buy many products, and products can be bought by many users: many-to-many.
i keep getting the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.UserProducts_dbo.Products_Product_ProductId' on table 'UserProducts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

i do want the cascade delete in order to delete products that belong to a user that deleted his account, or delete records from the UserProduct table that belong to a deleted user, or deleted product.
what am i doing wrong?

this is the User class:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }


    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Users")]
    public ICollection<Product> Cart { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
        Cart = new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

this is the Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }

    public byte[] Picture1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture3 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

Comment: nvm me saying but the Title stunned me for a moment lol

Comment: Have you added the foreign key reference in the model builder?

Comment: @j9070749 add to what?the collections: ef frame-work do it by convention when 2 entities has a collection of each other. and for the one-to-many i used foreign key annotation in the product model which should do the job.

Comment: The exception clearly tells you what's going on. You have to choose one foreign key that's capable of cascaded delete. Use fluent mappings to disable cascaded delete on the other FKs.

Comment: The exception saying there's an invalid constraint between the UserProducts to Product table. but why. if ef-framework creates the UserProducts table  the principles are the product and the user. deleting a record from the UserProducts shouldn't affect the product table nor the user's. yet deleting a product or a user record should. where is the invalid cascading?.@GertArnold

Comment: @UNlessofficialchannel When you delete `User`, the `UserProduct` can be deleted through (1) `User` -> `UserProduct` or (2) `User` -> `Product` -> `UserProduct`, hence *multiple cascade paths*.

Comment: @IvanStoev this is how i want it to work. What to do so the ef will accept it?

Comment: @UNlessofficialchannel Well, what you want is not always what you *can* get. Unfortunately this is EF limitation (originating from SqlServer database limitation) hence there is nothing you can do to let EF "accept it". All you can do is to follow Gert Arnold's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first i needed to write a class for the middle table in the many-to-many relationship users-to-products:

```
public class UserProduct
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

that allow me to disable the cascade on delete from this table to the User table (overriding the OnModelCreating in the context class):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProduct>().HasRequired(t => 
        t.User).WithMany(t => t.Cart).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

disabling the cascade works because:

1. it solves the multiple cascade path error.
2. deleting a user still deletes hes products and theirs UserProducts, 
   and deleting a product will delete its UserProducts.